# OSX El Capitan, Macbook pro

Tags: battery-life

My battery does not seem to last very long.  ca anything be done short of having the battery replaced?  I have tried the old full charge, use it till it dies and recharge, but without help

Comment: Can you add some specificity? How long is "very long"? What kind of applications are you running? What year/model/specs mbp?

Comment: It last maybe an hour and a half while surfing the net.  that and email is what I primarily do.  No power computing etc.

Comment: Add some specifics to your question like, what year your laptop is, how long does a full charge last, what type/how many applications are usually open?